# Test point not found error while adding test results to a test run using API

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-test-manager

Test point not found error while adding test results to a test run

I want to update the status of test cases in Microsoft Test Manager/VSTS using APi.

Following API is used to update the test results:

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/{project}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results?api-version={version}
Content-Type: application/json
```

JSON

```
{
  "testCaseTitle": { string },
  "testCase": {
    "id": { int }
  },
  "configuration": {
    "id": { int },
    "name": {string }
  },
  "testPoint": {
    "id": { int }
  },
  "state": {
    enum { Pending, Queued, InProgress, Paused, Completed }
  },
  "computerName": { string },
  "resolutionState": { string },
  "priority": { int },
  "failureType": { string },
  "automatedTestName": { string },
  "automatedTestStorage": { string },
  "automatedTestType": { string },
  "automatedTestId": { string },
  "area": {
    "name": {string}
  },
  "owner": {
   "DisplayName": {string}
  },
  "runBy": {
   "DisplayName": {string}
  },
  "outcome": {
        enum { None, Passed, Failed, Inconclusive, Timeout, Aborted, Blocked, NotExecuted, Warning, Error, NotApplicable, Paused, InProgress}
  },
  "errorMessage": { string },
  "comment": { string },
  "startedDate": { DateTime },
  "completedDate": { DateTime },
  "durationInMs": { long },
  "associatedBugs": [ 
    {
     { "id" : {int} }
    } 
  ]
}
```

For details refer: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/test/results?view=vsts#add-test-results-to-a-test-run

I created sample requests and checked the response (using Postman).

Request:

```
[
  {
    "testCase": {
      "id": 5000
    },
    "outcome": "Passed"
  }
]
```

Response:

```
404 Not Found
"message": "Test point 0 not found.",
```

Then somehere I read testPoint = no of configurations.
As my test case have one configuration, Operating system = Window 10; I set testPoint = 1.

(using Postman)
Request:

```
[
  {
    "testCase": {
      "id": 5000
    },
    "priority": 2,
    "configuration": {
      "id": 14,
      "name": "Windows 10"
    },
    "testPoint": {
      "id": 1
    },
    "outcome": "Passed"
  }
]
```

Response:

```
404 Not Found
"message": "Test point 1 not found.",
```

So I want to know what exactly is this testPoint and how to find it for a test case?
I want to call this API programatically from java code (for automation testing)? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

You need to specify the testpoint ID directly, for example:

```
[
      {
        "testPoint":{
            "id":144
        },
         "priority": 1,
         "outcome": "failed"
      }
   ]
```

You can get test point's id by using this REST API: [Get a test result](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/test/results?view=vsts#get-a-test-result)

Answer (score 0):

The source you refer to is adding a test result to a test run, not updating test results in a test run. You should refer to [Update test results for a test run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/test/results?view=vsts#update-test-results-for-a-test-run):

```
PATCH https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{teamproject}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results?api-version=3.0-preview

Content-Type: application/json

[
  {  
    "id": { int },
    "state": {
    enum { Pending, Queued, InProgress, Paused, Completed }
    },
    "computerName": { string },    
    "resolutionState": { string },
    "priority": { int },
    "failureType": { string }, 
    "owner": {
       "DisplayName": {string}
    },
    "runBy": {
       "DisplayName": {string}
    },
    "outcome": {
          enum { None, Passed, Failed, Inconclusive, Timeout, Aborted, Blocked, NotExecuted, Warning, Error, NotApplicable, Paused, InProgress}
    },
    "errorMessage": { string },
    "comment": { string },
    "startedDate": { DateTime },
    "completedDate": { DateTime },
    "durationInMs": { long },
    "associatedBugs": [ 
        {
         { "id" : {int} }
        } 
    ]
  }
]
```

You could [get the list of the test results for a test run](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/test/results?view=vsts#get-a-list-of-test-results) first, and then capture the test result you want to update to the Update API, and modify the values there.

```
https://{account}.visualstudio.com/{teamproject}/_apis/test/runs/{run}/results?api-version=3.0-preview
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is an API to get testPoints,for details refer:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/integrate/previous-apis/test/points?view=vsts#get-a-list-of-test-points